# Path to created sqlite database different iPad Simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created one application which using sqlite database.For first some time i have tested it on to the simulator .It was working fine on the simulator it shows the path of document directory:

```
Library/Application support/iPhone simulator/5.1/Application/UUID/document/database.sqlite
```

But when i put my application on iPad my application suddenly exited when i tried to do database operation printing some other path where my database is not present. What i have to do with this ? Please give me some solution to overcome this problem.

Comment: Actually, it was only accidentally working on the simulator.  See J2theC's post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to dynamically look for the proper directory. Since this is a database, you might want to put it in the document directory. Here's a piece of code to take care of it:

```
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]
```

Comment: you are asking the file manager default instance to provide you with a path of the document directory in the user domain directory. The response of the directory url will change under the simulator/device, but it will give you an equivalent url.